# How to make a target camera?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, graphics

I want to make a target camera like DCC tools(maya, houdini etc...). Things don't go as planned. I tried, but in vain.
Please tell me what to do.

```
void GLWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    const int dx = event->x() - _lastPosition.x();
    const int dy = event->y() - _lastPosition.y();

    if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        QQuaternion q1(QQuaternion::fromAxisAndAngle(_viewCamera->getUpVector(), dx));
        _viewCamera->setQuat((_viewCamera->getQuat() * q1));
        _viewCamera->setTranslation(q1 * _viewCamera->getTranslation());
        QQuaternion q2(QQuaternion::fromAxisAndAngle(_viewCamera->getRightVector(), dy));
        _viewCamera->setQuat((_viewCamera->getQuat() * q2));
        _viewCamera->setTranslation(q2 * _viewCamera->getTranslation());
    }
}
```

Camera has transform.

```
struct Transform
{
protected:
    QVector3        _translation;
    QQuaternion     _rotation;
    QVector3        _scale;
}
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific than "things don't go as planned"?  Exactly what do you expect to happen, and what actually happens?

Comment: I want to move a camera like url.
https://youtu.be/re82sOFQ6BM?t=1m4s

Comment: and what happens with the code you have written?

Comment: I never know which way the camera is going to fly.
I use Qt Library.
I'm afraid my expressions may be rude or hard to read, because I'm not so good at English.